# Saying a bracha right before one is niftar - is it significant?

Tags: blessing, death

I have heard many times that it is a big zechus or one to say a bracha, specifically Shehakol, as their last words here on earth before they pass away.

I am looking for a source for  this. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: If you die after saying shehakol before drinking then your last action is a bracha levatala

Comment: And really no one knows when they're going to die

Comment: @DoubleAA How so? If he dies after saying shehakol before drinking, then that is something that is not in his hands. Everyone has the potential to die after making any beracha; that doesn't stop one from making a beracha.

Comment: @Fawaz how not so? It's literally so. The fact that the death was out of his control means he's exempt from punishment. It's still hardly an ideal way to go. None us wish to violate prohibitions, even against our wills.

Comment: In the introduction of the Gesher Hachaim, the son of the author describes the passing away of his holy father, and brings up that he asked for a glass of water to say a *sheakol*. and *borei nefashot*. He asked for other things after that (his face to the west, open window, turning to the right. He said Viddui last.

Comment: In Sanhedrin 68a it mentions that when R' Eliezer was nifter he died saying the word Tahor and his Neshma left Tahor, which seems to show there may be significance to what you say right before you die. (see also Baba Metzia 86a and Avodah Zarah 27b and the Maharsha on the latter)

Answer (score 2):

I once heard this from Rav Gedaliah Schorr (on a recording  not in person) As I recall he said that Seforim say that a tzaddik who lives his entire life with a vibrant emuna that everything that transpires is by the word of Hashem, merits that his last words testify to just that: 'Shehakol nehiye bidvoro-all exists by His word.'"

Answer (score 1):

A big Talmid Chacham once told my brother that its source is a Rema miPanu (Rav Menachem Azarya from Panu (1548-1620). I will see if I can find it.